# twitter profile widget not showing in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter

I created a profile widget in twitter and i got the following code they said just copy and paste in yout html. but its not showing.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/in_DNA" data-widget-id="244847523552952***">Tweets by @in_DNA</a>

!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

i copied this code to my footer and sidebar, but not showing tweets.

is there any better plugin for this?
please help.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is for a good Twitter plugin, I suggest Twitter Widget Pro. I use it on my website, and never had problems. Very customizable using CSS.

See: http://bluedogwebservices.com/wordpress-plugin/twitter-widget-pro/

If you're looking to get the code you posted to work, then you may need to add the JS to an external file and include it in your header or footer file. You can't just paste JS into your widget.